# What images can you store in lxd containers?

Tags: lxc, container, lxd

What kinds of images can you store in LXD containers ?

Comment: I would assume you can store all image types in an LXD container. There should be few limitations as long as the OS can read it. If there's no legible documentation online, trial-and-error never hurts.

Comment: I heard there was a special "LXD" image you can store in it, but is it just storage, or is it like a virtual machine, you can RUN one in a container and access it ?

Comment: From the documentation, it looks like you can do both as long as you have  the right virtualization. It looks like you can remotely execute the file if you needed it for network distribution, or open it and view its contents as is. [source](https://linuxcontainers.org/lxd/getting-started-cli/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://insights.ubuntu.com/2015/04/28/getting-started-with-lxd-the-container-lightervisor/ for information on lxc

The “lxc” command line tool lets you interact with one or multiple LXD daemons. By default it will interact with the local daemon, but you can easily add more of them.

> As an easy way to start experimenting with remote servers, you can add
>   our public LXD server at https://images.linuxcontainers.org:8443
>
> That server is an image-only read-only server, so all you can do with
>   it is list images, copy images from it or start containers from it.
>
> You’ll have to do the following to: add the server, list all of its
>   images and then start a container from one of them:

```
lxc remote add images images.linuxcontainers.org
lxc image list images:
lxc launch images:ubuntu/trusty/i386 ubuntu-32
```

images listed here : http://images.linuxcontainers.org/images/

> [DIR] centos/ 2014-07-09 03:27    -     [DIR] debian/ 2015-05-12 00:20    -
>   [DIR] fedora/ 2016-01-04 03:44    -     [DIR] gentoo/ 2014-01-28 11:15    -
>   [DIR] opensuse/   2014-06-25 22:40    -     [DIR] oracle/ 2014-01-15 18:12    -
>   [DIR] plamo/  2014-01-14 20:28    -     [DIR] ubuntu/ 2015-11-10 20:22    -